# Can I exclude a file from being searched when doing refactoring with ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, resharper

Is there any way, when doing e.g. a rename class refactoring with ReSharper, I can exclude certain files or projects in the solution from being searched?

I have one project in my solution that ReSharper takes forever to search through whenever I run a rename class, and I know that in 99% of the time, the refactoring does not affect this project.

Comment: You can ignore certain files during solution-wide analysis, but I don't know of any way to ignore files during refactoring.

Comment: I guess unloaded projects would be ignored by R#.

Answer (score 0):

You could always make a second solution that doesn't include that project. Build the full solution on your continuous integration server, but open the smaller one when you're developing.